# spark: No of records in DataFrame is different in different runs

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, teradata

I am running a spark job that reads data from teradata. The query looks like

```
select * from db_name.table_name sample 5000000;
```

I'm trying to pull sample of 5 million rows of data. When I tried to print the number of rows in the result DataFrame, it is giving different results each time I run. Sometimes it is `4999937` and sometimes it is `5000124`. Is there any particular reason for this kind of behaviour?

**EDIT #1:**

The code I'm using:

```
val query = "(select * from db_name.table_name sample 5000000) as data"

var teradataConfig = Map("url"->"jdbc:teradata://HOSTNAME/DATABASE=db_name,DBS_PORT=1025,MAYBENULL=ON",
    "TMODE"->"TERA",
    "user"->"username",
    "password"->"password",
    "driver"->"com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver",
    "dbtable" -> query)

var df =  spark.read.format("jdbc").options(teradataConfig).load()

df.count
```

Comment: Probably some other process is modifying database in between.

Comment: I'm sure that no process is modifying this table. And that table has 300+ millions of rows. That's why I'm selecting 5 million only to debug something.

Comment: Can you show coding?

Comment: Hi, not sure, but maybe it's due to the statistical purpose of SAMPLE. Did you try TOP instead? (select TOP 5000000 * from db_name.table_name;)

Comment: I tried with `TOP` but still getting different number when getting the `count`.

Answer (score 0):

Try caching the resultant dataframe and perform count action on the dataframe

```
df.cache()
println(s"Record count: ${df.count()}
```

From here on when you reuse the df to create new dataframe or any other transformation you don't get mismatched counts since it is already in cache.

Make sure you have given enough memory to hold the cached dataframe in memory.

Comment: But is there any reason why the count is different than 5 million?

Comment: Not sure question is answered.